# What are the configurations of wicked_pdf. I have tried multiple times but can't figure it what's the issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I am using Ubuntu 18. I installed Wickedpdf using gem. Also installed wkhtmltopdf(using gem). I followed the instructions on their git repo but it's not generating a pdf.

Also, can I use a link to pdf without passing instance variable ?

Like in the following link I have to pass an instance variable which I don't need:

`<%= link_to 'Create PDF document', test_report_utils_path(@building, :format => :pdf) %>`

P.S:  I'm new to Rails. I don't know much about it.

Comment: can you at least give the code you have written?

Comment: Thanks @KSDPutra. Next time I'll write it in more details. I have resolved the issue and explained it in my answer  below.

Answer (score 1):

I was using following code.

```
@data = Test.report_data
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.pdf do
    render :pdf => "report",
           :template => "reports/show.pdf.erb",
           :layout => "pdf.html.erb",
           :locals => {:data => @data}
  end
end
```

And my wicked_pdf.rb in config looks like this.

```
WickedPdf.config = {
exe_path: '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf'
```

}

But I what I had is to create a symlink of wkhtmltopdf into another directory. Because in default it was looking somewhere else. Following command resolved my issue.

```
ln -s /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
```

Comment: Why create a symlink instead of pointing `exe_path` at `/usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf`?

Comment: @Unixmonkey That's also a good option. But I followed the an existing solution.  Would give it a try.